# Ajax POST format with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a form, inside which I want to have a "virtual form", which handles file attachments. I have a File-input and a button to send the file.

The problem is that my PHP backed gets only POST and that with structure:

```
"file"; filename="xxx.jpg"
Content-type: image/jpeg

.
.
.
```

where the dots represent the binary data from the file.

From what I have read it should be `$_FILES` and `$_POST` variables but I don't get them.

Here are the relevant codelines in HTML and in Javascript:

```
<input type="file" id="file-to-append" name="file-attachment">
<input type="button" onClick="append_file()" value="Add file">

function append_file() {
var formData = new FormData();


console.log(jQuery('#file-to-append'));
  formData.append('file', jQuery(":file")[0].files[0]);

  jQuery.ajax({
       url : 'file_upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert("Added");
       }
  });
}
```

Could somebody spot or know where the problem lies?

Comment: I bet you dont have an `enctype` attribute in your `form` tag.

Comment: post your complete form..

Comment: enctype wouldn't matter in this case

Comment: Please add your PHP code as well

Comment: PHP code it's currently just print_r of $_POST and $_FILES. I know what to do, when these give the correct values. (actually file_put_contents of those, as this is a "backend call")

Answer (score 0):

The data is passing properly so there is no problem with your Ajax call.

You get the file object in PHP using the super global `$_FILES`.

In your case, you would use it like:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
echo $file['name'];
echo $file['tmp_name'];
.
.
.
```

To take a look at the `$_FILES` array you could:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are getting stranger and stranger. I got it working, but only on IE 11 by setting contentType: 'multipart/form-data' With Chrome it doesn't work at all with that setting.

I have tried with contentType: false, but it doesn't work on either platform though it should be the right thing(TM) to do :/.

I have also added enctype-setting in the outer form, but I wonder how it could help, because I am not submitting (whole form) but only adding things "inside" the main form (that I handle myself). Apparently it didn't help either.

This shouldn't be a problem but for some reason I am stuck with this ajax implementation, though I have used file upload since long time ago (two figure number)...

hank

Answer (score -1):

Use right encrypte in your form

```
<form id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<input type="submit"  value="Add file">
</form>
```

use ajax submit

```
$("form#data").submit(function() 
{var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({

                    url: "filename.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                           var errFlag =jsonData.errorFlag;
                            var errMsg  =jsonData.errorMessage;

                            if(errFlag == 1)
                            {   
                                //successmessage;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //errormessage;
                            }
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false

                });
                return false;


});
```